# how to call API in flutter?

Tags: flutter

In my flutter app I want to call two APIs. For example API A and API B .
If API A loads data then call API B and show API B data in listView. 
How can I pass API A data as parameter to the API B?

after API A loads data successfully and disply in drop down then call API B.
this is my code:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

      body: new SafeArea(

          child: new Form(

              child: new ListView(

                children: <Widget>[
               FutureBuilder('API A data'),
               Container(
              FutureBuilder('API B data'),
              )]))
```

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: i have call two api in  Widget build() method using future builder

Comment: Please show us what you have done. No one can help you with this much information. We need to see the code.

Comment: Have you attempted the answers?

Answer (score 4):

You might want to create controllers (just a class which contains important functions/business logic - mostly used for manipulation of data) so that it's easier to maintain.

Ex.

```
class LoginController {
    static Future<http.Response> login(
        {@required String email, @required String password}) async {
    var params = {
        'email': email,
        'password': password,
    };

    var response = await http.post(ApiRoute.LOGIN,
        body: json.encode(params));

    /// If the first API call is successful
    if (response.statusCode == HttpStatus.ok) {
        var secondResponse = SecondController.anothrFunction();

        /// Do something related to the response of second api call here
    }

    /// Do other stuffs here

        return response;
    }
}

class SecondController {
     static Future<http.Response> anotherFunction(
      {@required String something}) async {
    var params = {
      'something': something,
    };

    var response = await http.post(ApiRoute.SOMETHING,
        body: json.encode(params));
    return response;
  }
}
```

Then you can just call `LoginController.login`, and that would call both APIs.

Answer (score 2):

You can call an Api with the http package, and you can chain the calls to use the result of the first call in the second, like this:

```
void callApis(){
  http.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos").then((result){
    int itemId = json.decode(result.body)[2]['id'];

    http.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/$itemId").then((result){
      print(result.body);
    });
  });
}
```

Make sure you imported the `http` package on the top of your class:

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
```

Comment: i fetch api data but how to call frist API A and after API loads data successfully then call API B

Comment: The way I showed on the response. We are using a `.then()` which will only run once you get the response from the first call.